# Apache Solr: How to update metadata information without reindexing the binary data content

Tags: solr

We are leveraging Solr capabilities to support full document search capabilities whereby users can search on the content within the documents. Further, metadata info is associated with each of the documents so that search could be achieved on metadata as well

Till this time everything is fine. However when only the metadata info needs to be updated (i.e. the document itself has not undergone any change), I am not able to figure suitable mechanism whereby I could only update the metadata info (and is not required to re-index the document). Since I could not figure any appropriate solution, I am re-indexing the document as well as updating the associated metadata info. I know that this is an inelegant solution. Seek you help to know ways & means to achieve metadata info update without the need to re-index the binary document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its the Metadata apart from the metadata retrieved from the document itself, you can check for Partial updates to the Document with Solr.

With Solr 4.0 you can do a [Partial update of all those document](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/) with just the fields that have changed will keeping the complete document same.  The id should match.

However, if the metadata is inbuilt document metadata you would probably need to reindex the data as the retrieval is done by Tika **OR** you have a seperate program to use Tika independant to retrieve the document metadata and update the document partially.

Comment: This is perfectly fitting solution. Thanks so much! I do not have words to express my sincere thanks